# AWS: Can't add a user to an account without specifying a permission set tho the user is already in a group that's in the account with a permission set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

To repro:

- Start a new account
- Agree to the IAM and Organisation stuff.
- Make two standard permission sets: SystemAdministrator and ViewOnlyAccess.
- Make a group and a user, the user being in the group.
- Add the group to the account with the SystemAdministrator permission set.
- Try to add the user.
- Notice that you must choose a permission set in order to add the user. I think it should be OK to add the user with no permission set cos they inherit the SystemAdministrator permission from the group anyway.
- Choose the ReadOnlyUser set
- Log in as this user and notice that both SystemAdministrator and ReadOnlyUser are offered, thus showing that indeed the SystemAdministrator permission set was inherited from the group.
- Choose SystemAdministrator and launch an instance to further confirm the same.
- Remove the permission set from the user and notice that it gets removed from the account without confirmation.

I think this is harmful because you must do one of some undesirable things. If you add the SystemAdministrator PS to both group and user then restricting the group's permissions later will have no effect on such users, but there may be other users who were already in the account for other reasons and were subsequently added to the group, and this latter group will be affected by restrictions to the group's permissions. Nobody asked for that, and it's a mess. If you decide against adding the PS to the group, then what are groups for? The only clean fix would be to make a PS that allows nothing at all and add the user to it, but I'm gonna guess that AWS disallows empty permission sets for the same reason it disallows permissionless users.

What's wrong with permissionless users anyway? Unix has allowed users with passwords disabled since the dawn of time because it's useful.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem?  I create permissionless IAM Users all the time: just select "attach an existing Policy" (or whatever that string is) then don't attach anything.  There is no requirement that an IAM User have attached Policies.